# How to pass variable from page to another page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, variables

I want to ask how to pass a variable from a page to another page.

example.

in (page1.aspx.cs) there is button click and textbox

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1.text = ;

    }
```

in (page2.aspx.cs)

A = "hello"
// A is variable that can be change, A variable is coming from microC

What I want is show "hello" from page2 in textbox1.text when I click button1 in page1.aspx

Comment: There are various ways to do this. Which one is the "right" way depends on what problem you want to solve. Can you elaborate a bit? Is `A` just a constant defined in page2 (then it should not be in a page) or is it a variable that can be changed (then you should tell us about how this happens, i.e., how does the user interaction work). Oh, and please don't use all caps in the title. It's rude to shout. ;-)

Comment: im sory for using caps in the title.i just dont know it. A is variable in page 2 that can be change. variable A in page 2 is coming from microC

Comment: How can it be changed? And how is its value persisted (i.e. stored)? And what is microC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the value as a querystring parameter.

So if you are using `Response.Redirect` you could do something like

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?value=" + taxtbox1.text);
}
```

On Page 2 you can get the value using `Request["value"].ToString()`

Notice that the querystring parameter name is what you request. So if you have ?something=else you will Request["something"]

Answer (score 0):

1. Without a [Postback](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/submit-and-postback) it is not possible!
2. With a Postback, yes it is (see [Cross Page Postback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx)). Also see in the link what you can have access to! (Access possibilities are page controls & public members).
3. Other options, Session variables, cookies, query string, etc!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to place the value into some form of temporary storage: Cookie, Session, etc.  And then redirect.

Another would be to redirect with a query string value.  It really depends on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend setting a session if this is necessary.

```
Session["sessionname"] = "";
```

Though it isn't ideal, is it possible to have everything on page1? You can switch with a panel control.

Answer (score 0):

u can use one of this ways:
1- Query string

```
page.aspx?ID=111&&Name=ahmed
```

2- Session

```
Session["session1"] = "your value";
```

3- Public property

```
public String prop1
    {
        get
        {
           return txt_Name.Text;
        }
    }
```

4- Controls Data
5- HttpPost